# Spring WebFlux Security Custom AccessDeniedHandler

Tags: spring, spring-security, kotlin, spring-webflux

I have a REST endpoint where access is restricted to ADMIN users only:

```
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
fun getAll(): Flux<User> {
    return Flux.fromIterable(userRepository.findAll())
}
```

When I try to access this endpoint with a non-ADMIN user, I get a 403 with a `denied` response (a non JSON response).

How can I customize the response to still receive a 403 response, but with a JSON message something like

```
{
   "error": "Access denied"
}
```

The `SecurityWebFilterChain` I'm implementing:

```
return http.csrf().disable()
    .formLogin().disable()
    .httpBasic().disable()
    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler { exchange, denied -> ???? }
    .and()
    .authorizeExchange()
    .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
    .pathMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
    .anyExchange().authenticated()
    .and().csrf().disable()
    .logout().disable()
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have not done this in Kotlin, but in Java you have to implement the `org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ServerAccessDeniedHandler` interface:

```
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements ServerAccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = serverWebExchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        String responseBody = "{\"error\": \"" + accessDeniedException.getLocalizedMessage() + "\"}";
        byte[] bytes = responseBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        DataBuffer buffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer));
    }
}
```

Then you can pass it to the `accessDeniedHandler()` method:

```
return http.csrf().disable()
    .formLogin().disable()
    .httpBasic().disable()
    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
    .and()
    .authorizeExchange()
    .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
    .pathMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
    .anyExchange().authenticated()
    .and().csrf().disable()
    .logout().disable()
    .build();
```

When testing my endpoint in Postman, I get a "403 Forbidden" error with a response body of:

```
{
    "error": "Access Denied"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom filter and modify the response when you get 403 error.
Something like this:

```
class AuthorizationModifierFilter : Filter {
    ....

    fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain): Unit {
        // Check whether the status code is 403 and modify the response
    }
}
```

And register your filter:

```
return http.csrf().disable()
    .formLogin().disable()
    .httpBasic().disable()
    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler { exchange, denied -> ???? }
    .and()
    .authorizeExchange()
    .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
    .pathMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
    .anyExchange().authenticated()
    .and().addFilterAfter(AuthorizationModifierFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java.class)
    .and().csrf().disable()
    .logout().disable()
    .build()
```